# Delphi 64bit mac os app

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

is there a fix for the app store for the Mac OS platform? I create my apps with Firemonkey but it's been a while that I am NOT able to upload my works. There is the warning about the compatibility from apple but still nothing!

From June 1, 2018 the 64 bit version is **needed** but we are in august and still nothing.

I have seen that David Nottage put a temporary fix to android sdk target. I have tested that because I need android too. It changes some libraries and the manifest. Do I have to do something similar with mac os apps?

Is there any tutorial online?

---

I have googled a lot but I didnt have success. Maybe it's me that I am weak at googling stuff but nothing.

Comment: If there is NOT a solution, well Embarcadero is ridicolous also because the website claims that you can do apps for mac app store and android store! It's fake info and people pay a lot for the licence. Dont surprise if Delphi loses interest.....

Comment: Forget Google, try https://duckduckgo.com/ :) But anyway, how can we help?

Comment: @Victoria Thank you!! I do not know, maybe you expert know some place where I can find a fix. You see, an article like (http://delphiworlds.com/2018/05/targeting-android-8-and-higher/) that explains how to fix...

Comment: ... and that's why I've dropped Delphi and moved to Qt ;)

Comment: I do not know c++ I cannot use Qt. I know Delphi and java but I cannot go iOS with java so I need firemonkey alberto!!

Comment: You can't fix the lack of a 64 bit compiler for macOS in Delphi; Embarcadero need to do that

Comment: This is not professional by the way, at least the could not claim to be able to target android/mac stores :/

Comment: @Dave, they can steal the FPC one and pretend it's theirs :)

Comment: Embarcadero are aware that their website makes erroneous claims but in spite of this being pointed out to them, they have decided not to remove the false statements. In your position I'd be evaluating other tools.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if the website claims the fake they also could be accused and someone could start legal actions. It's not my case of course but that would be a good lesson!

Comment: I like Xamarin. Not just because Visual Studio is far much better than Delphi IDE, it's much more benevolent with wider community and frequent updates. And things are just working there as it seems that MS is testing their products (sorry for such sarcasm against EMBT).

Comment: @Victoria Yes I was planning to go Xamarin!! Not Qt because I don't like c++. I have been coding in java since 2002 I have a long experience, I see that C# is similar. Do you thing that C# is hard? I was considering to buy a good C# book

Comment: Yes, I'd say C# is pretty close to Java. But I was able to move even from Delphi to C# pretty quickly. In the end it's just a _"different syntax"_ (semantics remain). C++ is a bit more complex (but also more flexible, due to templates etc.).

Comment: If you have complaints about Embarcadero, post them at their forums. This is not the place for such discussions.

Comment: You can still build for macOS and distribute to your customers. It is only Mac App Store that has this hard limit, preventing upload from 1. june. A macOS user that downloads your installer from your website can install and use your macOS program. They will just see a warning first time they run the program that it is not updated.

Comment: @Victoria: are you advertising M$ products or got something technically valuable to say? Xamarin is completely different than FMX and Delphi, you don't even say which mode are you talking about (Xamarin Forms or platform-depentant sub-projects). Please believe me, the frequent updates are a big disadvantage, especially when everything breaks, including connectivity with the mobile device. I've ACTUALLY used it and maturity of Xamarin is even less than FMX one.

Comment: @DaveNottage can you provide any link to prove it? I have found the following: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/102/ (from the movie transcript: "Last year, we announced that High Sierra was the last MacOS release to fully support 32-bit apps without compromise. And this year, we're announcing that MacOS Mojave is the last release to support 32-bit at all."

Comment: Yes, sorry.. I missed that announcement about it being moved to Mojave, thanks :-)

Comment: @RosannaTrevisan you should seriously consider Oxygene (https://www.elementscompiler.com/elements/oxygene).  It is not cross-platform (a la FMX or Xamarin), but there is a cross-platform RTL (with some Delphi RTL compatibility).  Platform specifics (such as the UI) do require platform specific code, but this results in "first class citizen" apps.  Even the RTL eventually compiles down to platform native code.  And done right, your UI is a very thin layer over your applications capabilities.  RemObjects own IDE is predominantly single source for macOs [Fire: released] and Windows [Water: beta]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no fix at the moment because there is no 64 bit Delphi compiler for Mac OSX. You smply have to hope that Embarcadero release one soon.

Comment: I will look for another tool for sure. Firemonkey it's not good, not stable and cannot even be useful to upload apps

Comment: @RosannaTrevisan FreePascal/Lazarus supports OSX 64bit development. And you can compile a lot of Delphi (but not FireMonkey) code with FreePascal.

Comment: @Rosanna: that is your opinion. Any serious points? Your question regarded the non-existing 64bit compiler. That compiler did not exist when the newest Delphi version was developed. That compiler was not needed by Apple. After some time, Apple changed their regulations and now requires 64bit executables for macOS. What kind of brilliant reasoning get you to the point that "Firemonkey is not good and not stable"?

Comment: This is not valuable answer. The answer does not contain information about Delphi version, so in the future (when hopefully 64bit macOS compiler will be available) it may lead to misunderstandings.

Comment: @zdrichs That's a separate opinion about FMX. Regarding the 64 bit compiler, Emba don't have a great record of being ahead of the curve here. They were terribly late on Windows. They were last minute for iOS.  It was not a a surprise that 64 bit is required for app store. This should have been dealt with years ago.

Comment: @zdichs As for how valuable the answer is, it matches the question I suppose. Perhaps one of us could edit the question to include a version.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sure, but you personally fight very often with opinion-based comments and questions. I think that we should discuss about facts. The question was not about being "good" or "stable", but about the availability of 64bit compiler. So IMHO this place is not for putting subjective comments and advertisements of the tools (as recomendation of the tools are not welcomed here, are they?)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: poor question, without exact version certainly needs perfect answer. We can suppose that version is Tokyo, but who knows, maybe it is old XE2? ;)

Comment: @zdichs I don't think I said anything subjective, made comments about stability or anything like that. You seem quite sensitive to the criticisms that others have made though. And I see you wrote M$ which opens you up to criticism for being anti Microsoft. If you don't think people here should be making subjective comments, you should perhaps set a good example yourself.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sure not you but Rosanna made some extremely subjective comments and my comment contained "$" to point out useless advertisements there. I will try to remind you next time, when the discussion will lead to "opinion-based" matters :)

Comment: @zdichs Actually I'd say that you made some quite subjective criticisms of xamarin.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: ad rem: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/get-started/hello-mac proves that Xamarin.Mac is essentially different than FMX approach (Mac required to develop, cannot design on Windows); https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/wiki/Platform-Support-macOS-Status - proves that Xamarin.Forms are at *Preview* stage at the moment, not ready for production (2018.08); https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/4288 - Xamarin not ready for Mojave macOS "Hardened Runtime" - limitations for JIT tech. Please also compare the control list in Xamarin.Forms against FMX set.

Answer (score 11):

Per Embarcadero's [current roadmap](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/exciting-rad-studio-developments-in-2018), support for Mac OSX 64bit is planned for RAD Studio 10.3:

> [Key roadmap themes](https://community.embarcadero.com/article/16563-rad-studio-roadmap-september-2017) for 10.3 (and 10.3.x) include **macOS 64-bit support**, C++17 support, consolidating our debuggers and updating the IDE UI/UX, in addition to FireMonkey z-order support on Android and more.

Note that 10.3 is scheduled to start beta testing soon (invites went out a few days ago), so it will likely be released sometime this Fall.  Users with an active [Update Subscription](https://www.embarcadero.com/update-subscription) have early access to betas for "hotfixes, updates, and **major “next” versions**". Otherwise, contact Embarcadero to become a beta tester if you can't wait for the final release.

---

**Update:** Embarcadero has just released a [new roadmap](https://community.embarcadero.com/article/news/16638-rad-studio-august-2018-roadmap), and [clarified their plan regarding OSX 64-bit support](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/august-2018-roadmap-commentary-from-product-management):

> One roadmap change you may notice compared to the September 2017 roadmap is that **we removed macOS 64-bit platform support from the initial 10.3 release**.
>
> This doesn’t mean that we don’t think macOS 64-bit is important. We removed it from the 10.3 release to focus on providing more quality and stability for the other key features that are in flight. With that said, **our intent is to provide support for macOS 64-bit, including support for targeting the iOS 11 (and iOS 12) simulators, in a follow-on 10.3.x release**. We know that developers looking to target the macOS App Store or leverage 64-bit APIs require macOS 64-bit support.
>
> We have a number of customers today who distribute their existing 32-bit applications through their own web store and are currently not impacted by this Apple requirement.